# Python script can't see my modules

Tags: python

I have a project set up like this:

```
panel/
   configure.py
   run.py
   panel/
      __init__.py
      mailer.py
      helpers/
         __init__.py
         gearman.py
```

`mailer.py` includes the import `from helpers.gearman import ExceptionalGearmanWorker`. `mailer.py` also includes an `if __name__ == '__main__'` check to run the program when invoked from the command line.

From the top-level `panel/` directory I want to run `python panel/mailer.py`. When I try to run this, `mailer.py` is unable to import from `gearman.py`. The specific error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "panel/mailer.py", line 14, in <module>
    from panel.cgearman import ExceptionalGearmanWorker
ImportError: No module named panel.cgearman
```

It looks like running the script directly, from within `panel/` doesn't add `panel/` to the import path? Is this correct? Can I make this work somehow?

Comment: `panel/` and `helpers/` should have `__init__.py`'s.  Can you `import panel` fine?  If not, you might have a `PYTHONPATH` problem too.

Comment: My directories do have these but I forgot to include them in my outline. I've updated my question to list these--thanks though.

Comment: @jszakmeister if I run the python interactive interpreter from the top-leve panel/ directory, yes, I can run "import panel" without error.